# Почему не работает в сопоставлении с образцом значения заданного типа-ограничителя?

Tags: haskell, сопоставление-с-образцом

```
-- test1.hs 
-- :l test1
class StampValue sv

class Particle p where
   detect :: (StampValue s) => p -> Int -> s -> Bool

data QValue = R | G | S deriving (Eq)

instance StampValue QValue

data Quantum = Quantum QValue QValue QValue deriving (Eq)

instance Particle Quantum where
   detect _ _ S = error "nonsense" -- Почему нельзя испльзовать S?
-- works: detect _ _ _ = True
```

По идее, в этом примере тип `QValue` является инстанцией класса StampValue. В функции `detect` как раз и имеем ограничитель `(StampValue s) =>`. Так почему же я не могу использовать значение этого типа `S` в качестве сопоставителя по образцу?

---

Другой пример с аналогичной проблемой:

```
-- test2.hs 
-- :l test2
class StampValue sv

class Particle p where
   detect :: (StampValue s) => p -> Int -> s -> Bool

type CValue = Bool

instance StampValue Bool -- CValue is an instance of StampValue

data Classical = Classical CValue CValue CValue

instance Particle Classical where
   detect (Classical x _ _) _ False = error "Only True" -- Почему нельзя Bool?
   -- хотя мы задали, что Bool это инстанция StampValue 
   -- (без этой строчки компилится нормально)
   detect (Classical x _ _) 0 _ = x
   detect (Classical _ y _) 1 _ = y
   detect (Classical _ _ z) 2 _ = z
   detect (Classical _ _ _) _ _ = error "the index is out of range"
```

---

Сообщение **ghci** при попытки откомпилировать:

```
    Couldn't match expected type ‘s’ with actual type ‘Bool’ (или ‘QValue’)
      ‘s’ is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for
            detect :: (StampValue s) => Classical -> Int -> s -> Bool
...
```

---

Хотя, казалось бы:

```
cmpSpecial :: (Eq e, Num e) => e -> e -> Bool
cmpSpecial _ 0 = False
cmpSpecial 0 _ = False
cmpSpecial x y = (x == y)
```

так работает, хотя тут `e` тоже не тип

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Числовые литералы - это не настоящие конструкторы данных, и сопоставление с ними отличается от других случаев сопоставления.

Например

```hs
f 0 = "zero"
f _ = "nonzero"
```

разворачивается во что-то (очень схематично) похожее на

```hs
f x =
  case x == fromInteger 0 of
    True  -> "zero"
    False -> "nonzero"
```

Как следствие, `f` должна иметь сигнатуру

```hs
f :: (Eq a, Num a) => a -> String
```

Т.е. необходимо, чтобы числовой тип помимо прочего реализовывал `Eq`, чего не требуется для сопоставления с конструктором.

В вашем случае телом функции подразумевается, что тип третьего параметра - `QValue`, и только с ним функция способна работать, хотя согласно сигнатуре она должна принимать более общий тип.

Проще всего в этой ситуации будет воспользоваться расширениями GHC

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeSynonymInstances #-}

class Particle p s where
   detect :: p -> Int -> s -> Bool

data QValue = R | G | S deriving (Eq)

data Quantum = Quantum QValue QValue QValue deriving (Eq)

type CValue = Bool

data Classical = Classical CValue CValue CValue

instance Particle Quantum QValue where
   detect _ _ S = error "nonsense"

instance Particle Classical CValue where
   detect (Classical x _ _) _ False = error "Only True"
   detect (Classical x _ _) 0 _ = x
   detect (Classical _ y _) 1 _ = y
   detect (Classical _ _ z) 2 _ = z
   detect (Classical _ _ _) _ _ = error "the index is out of range"
```

Comment: @extm Спасибо большое!